# Qt: accessing QGraphicsScene from another function results in Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to pass the QGraphicsScene as an argument to another class method after the ComboBox signal `currentIndexChanged`, but I am getting a `Segmentation fault` when I want to use the argument. Please, what am I doing wrong? Thank you

The constructor of mainwindow.cpp
connect(ui->comboBox_env_type, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(on_EnvironmentChanged(int)));

```
  _env_scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
  ui->graphicsView->setFixedSize(960, 800);
  ui->graphicsView->setFrameStyle(0);
  ui->graphicsView->setScene(_env_scene); 
  _env_discrete = new DiscreteEnvironment(_WIDTH, _HEIGHT, _ROWS);
  _env_discrete->MakeGrid(_env_scene);
```

Method in DiscreteEnvironment

```
void
DiscreteEnvironment::MakeGrid(QGraphicsScene* env_scene)
{
    env_scene->addLine(480, 0, 480, 800);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, compilable example but I would guess that `_env_scene` != `env_scene`